# Retrieve all models that are not associated with another model through pivot

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have three tables: `users`, `organizations`, `organization_user`. `organization_user` is a pivot table for the many-to-many relationship between `users` and `organizations`. The many-to-many relationships have been setup correctly in the corresponding models.

I need to obtain all users who are not associated with a given organization. How should this be done using eloquent. Below is what I have tried, but it is returning no results:

```
public function associate_user($organization_id){

        $data = [
            'organization'      => \App\Organization::find($organization_id),
            'users'             => \App\User::whereDoesntHave('organizations', function($query) use ($organization_id){
                $query->where('organization_id', $organization_id);
            })
        ];

        return view('admin.associateUser', $data);

    }
```

Comment: You forgot `->get();` after `whereDoesntHave`

Comment: 0_0...wow...I think it's time to call it a day. Thank you @DanMiller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are never actually executing the query.

You need to call `get()` at the end of the query builder.

```
public function associate_user($organization_id) {
    $data = [
        'organization' => \App\Organization::find($organization_id),
        'users'        => \App\User::whereDoesntHave('organizations', function($query) use ($organization_id){
            $query->where('organization_id', $organization_id);
        })->get(); // Add the call to get()
    ];
    return view('admin.associateUser', data);
}
```